# Angular input type="select url"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, url-validation

I have a `input` where you can type in a URL. Now I also like to add a suggestion list to the input where you can select predefined URLs.

My attempt was to change from `type=url` to `type=select` and provide a datalist:

```
<input type=select list=servers required ng-model=server />
<datalist id=servers>
    <option label="Server example 1" value="https://www.google.de/"/>
</datalist>
```

But now I am missing the URL validation from angular.
Is there a way to combine those two types? Or any other suggestion how I can do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't even make sense.  First, URL "validation" is an HTML5/browser feature, not an angular feature.  Second, there is no HTML `type="select"`;  select boxes are a completely different element type, they are not an `input`.

Comment: Btw you have defined the attribute "list" on the input but you have to define the "id" attribute on the datalist tag. Just use type "text" on your input.

Comment: Thanks, the missing ID was just a copy mistake from my side. The list is shown. But I thought I also need to edit the type. but it indeed looks like I do not need to change the type...

Answer (score 1):

the type "select" does not exist on input tag. To propose a suggestion maybe you can create an autocompletion system or just a select HTML tag with options.